# How to extract a Uri out of an Intent from ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER

Tags: android, android-intent, ringtonemanager

I recently started coding my really first android project using Android Studio 3.1.2 and SDK 19.

One of my Fragments opens a Ringtone picker by Intent using `Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)`, so user can select a ringtone, which Uri shall then saved to `SharedPreferences`. The picker opens as expected, but after I select a ringtone and press ok, i get this RuntimeException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo
{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity 
{com.procra.myProject/com.procra.myProject.Activities.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

When taking the result of the picker I pass the Intent of the result to my `SettingsHandler`, where `setNotificationRingtone()` should take care about the selected tone as below:

```
public synchronized static void setNotificationRingtone(Context context, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE_URI , data.getStringExtra("uriString")).apply();
    //this is the one I suspect to be the troublemaker
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("uriString")));
}
```

If I got that correct I somehow misunderstood the structure of the Intent `data` the `onActivityResult()`method returns. I tried to find an understandable answer here, but none of them really matched to my question.

I would appreciate it, if someone can explain, how to extract the result out of the Intent correctly and how to parse the according data from the intent to a Uri. Thanks in forward.

Comment: `One of my Fragments opens a Ringtone picker` : Ask the developer of `Ringtone picker` how ringtone is send back to caller via intent api. The question has no info wich `Ringtone picker` you are using. Or put a breakpoint into onActivityResult and use the debugger to inspect returned intent

Comment: @k3b i use the default one by `Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER

> Output: EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI.

so replace `data.getStringExtra("uriString")` with `data.getStringExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI)`

to verify put a debugger-breakpoint into onActivityResult and use the debugger to inspect returned intent

Comment: `getExtra()`does not exist in particular. I tried it via `Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI))` but it throws the same exception.

Comment: It's `getParcelableExtra()`, so for now it works, thanks for the help anyways